# Pivot: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I want to plot a heatmap between hashtags and username from the given final table after cleaning and pre-processing.
Getting the following error.

I have pasted the full error which I'm getting I searched on similar StackOverflow errors but was unable to get the correct result.

[image]

`final_sns = final.pivot("hashtags", "username")
 ax = sns.heatmap(final_sns)`

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-277e0506604d> in <module>()
----> 1 final_sns = final.pivot("hashtags", "username")
      2 ax = sns.heatmap(final_sns)

c:\users\apex_predator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
   5192         """
   5193         from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import pivot
-> 5194         return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
   5195 
   5196     _shared_docs['pivot_table'] = """

c:\users\apex_predator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
    413             indexed = self._constructor_sliced(self[values].values,
    414                                                index=index)
--> 415     return indexed.unstack(columns)
    416 
    417 

c:\users\apex_predator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   5532         """
   5533         from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import unstack
-> 5534         return unstack(self, level, fill_value)
   5535 
   5536     _shared_docs['melt'] = ("""

c:\users\apex_predator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in unstack(obj, level, fill_value)
    493     if isinstance(obj, DataFrame):
    494         if isinstance(obj.index, MultiIndex):
--> 495             return _unstack_frame(obj, level, fill_value=fill_value)
    496         else:
    497             return obj.T.stack(dropna=False)

c:\users\apex_predator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in _unstack_frame(obj, level, fill_value)
    507         unstacker = partial(_Unstacker, index=obj.index,
    508                             level=level, fill_value=fill_value)
--> 509         blocks = obj._data.unstack(unstacker)
    510         return obj._constructor(blocks)
    511     else:

c:\users\apex_predator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in unstack(self, unstacker_func)
   4608         unstacked : BlockManager
   4609         """
-> 4610         dummy = unstacker_func(np.empty((0, 0)), value_columns=self.items)
   4611         new_columns = dummy.get_new_columns()
   4612         new_index = dummy.get_new_index()

c:\users\apex_predator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in __init__(self, values, index, level, value_columns, fill_value, constructor)
    135 
    136         self._make_sorted_values_labels()
--> 137         self._make_selectors()
    138 
    139     def _make_sorted_values_labels(self):

c:\users\apex_predator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in _make_selectors(self)
    173 
    174         if mask.sum() < len(self.index):
--> 175             raise ValueError('Index contains duplicate entries, '
    176                              'cannot reshape')
    177 

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

What is that I am missing?

Comment: I've removed the seaborn tag and edited the title as your error is related to `pandas.pivot` and not to seaborn

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have duplicated rows in your DataFrame, so your Pivot doesn't know which row to to take while pivoting.

Try this [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) method to check them.